# Xcode 7 builds i386 instead of arm binary for Release-iphoneos

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, arm

I moved from XCode 6 to XCode 7 and without any changes to the source, or project, or anything my Archive builds started to fail.

After research on the error that `lipo` produced:

```
lipo:.../Release-iphoneos/libSDWebImage.a and .../Release-iphonesimulator/libSDWebImage.a have the same architectures (i386) and can't be in the same fat output file
```

I found that the following:

In XCode 6 the `lipo -info` returns `Architectures in the fat file: .../Release-iphoneos/libSDWebImage.a are: armv7 arm64` and `Architectures in the fat file: .../Release-iphonesimulator/libSDWebImage.a are: i386 x86_64` which is correct. I have arm for iphone device and i386 for iphone simulator.

In XCode 7 these two files are the same, and have the i386 architecture! So framework scripts that uses lipo to join these two `.a` files into one fails.

Why XCode 7 suddenly stopped building my `SDWebImage` framework for arm? The project settings are unchanged, the library is the same, the scheme has Archive set to Release. Please help.

```
iMac:~ lukasz$ lipo -info /Users/lukasz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/…-etcsjmgakpylpmgchumhnsqpyrev/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/adhoc-stage/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libSDWebImage.a
input file /Users/lukasz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/…-etcsjmgakpylpmgchumhnsqpyrev/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/adhoc-stage/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libSDWebImage.a is not a fat file
Non-fat file: /Users/lukasz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/…-etcsjmgakpylpmgchumhnsqpyrev/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/adhoc-stage/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libSDWebImage.a is architecture: i386

iMac:~ lukasz$ lipo -info /Users/lukasz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/…-etcsjmgakpylpmgchumhnsqpyrev/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/adhoc-stage/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphonesimulator/libSDWebImage.a
input file /Users/lukasz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/…-etcsjmgakpylpmgchumhnsqpyrev/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/adhoc-stage/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphonesimulator/libSDWebImage.a is not a fat file
Non-fat file: /Users/lukasz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/…-etcsjmgakpylpmgchumhnsqpyrev/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/adhoc-stage/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphonesimulator/libSDWebImage.a is architecture: i386
```

Comment: check the "Build Active Architecture Only" option in your target /Build Settings

Comment: @Igor it does not help

Comment: i think we used the same Ray Wenderlich tutorial...

Comment: Per the last comment on the Ray Wenderlich tutorial, this seems to be the problem. I have the same problem but have not yet been able to fix it.   With Product -> Archive, the BUILD_DIR is /Users/X/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-qwertyuiop/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/your-framework/BuildProductsPath
Within that directory, the two products Release-iphoneos and Release-iphonesimulator don't use their own libProjectName.a files but an alias to one in the directory UninstalledProducts. When this happens the latest build becomes the reference to which the alias's point.

Comment: It seems to got fixed in Xcode 7.1.1 (or 7.1), can you please reassure?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem trying to build a multi-architecture framework on Xcode 7. It seems like you are building a static library, which is different, but could be related. I'm assuming you are using `xcodebuild` command (in an Aggregate target run script?) to build your library for different SDKs and then doing `lipo` at the end to join all of them.

The problem for me was that the framework/library being built is located in the `build/UninstalledProducts` folder, and what lives in the `BUILD_DIR` are symlinks to that. So most likely the libraries in your `Release-iphoneos` and `Release-iphonesimulator` are aliases to the same one, hence you see that they have the same architecture (`i386` in your case).

To avoid this, navigate to the 'Build Settings' of your static library target in Xcode and ensure the following under 'Deployment':

1. `Deployment Location` is `NO` for release
2. `Deployment Postprocessing` is `NO` for release

You should see that the build no longer outputs `UninstalledProducts` folder and that all libraries/frameworks built in the `BUILD_DIR` are unique files, which should now have the correct architectures. You can then do whatever you like with them using `lipo`. You might have to delete your `DerivedData` before attempting the above.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the fix was to set the '[Skip install](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW36)' from Yes no No (which is the default). So insure that in addition to other two options mentioned by Andrew Wei. +1 for great analysis dude.

Comment: After making this change a generic archive gets created instead of an iOS app archive? Did you faced this problem too?

Comment: Yes, this is a side-effect of setting skip-install to false. But this discussion is about building a Framework/Static lib. so its not an issue unless you're trying to build an app which is co-hosted in the same framework project.